# Let $f(x)=e^{2x}$. The line L is the tangent to the curve of $f$ at $(1,e^2)$. Find the equation of $L$ in the form $y=ax+b$

Tags: calculus

please help ! calculus ! really need to do this for my final exam. HELP its tomorrow

Comment: What have you tried?  Certainly you've at least taken the derivative of $e^{2x}$ to find the slope of the tangent line?  You have a slope and a point on that line... do you know how to get the equation of a line from that?

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for a function $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is:
$$y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$

Answer (score 1):

First you get the derivative of $f(x) = e^{2x}$ which is $f^\prime(x) = 2e^{2x}$ by the chain rule. Now the line is tangent to $f(x)$ at $(1,e^2)$ then they have the same slope. Now the slope of $f(x)$ at $(1,e^2)$ is $f^\prime(1) = 2e^{2}$. and now you should use the formula $$m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$, Your $m$ is the slope that you found which is $2e^2$ and just substitute the point $(1,e^2)$ as $(x_1,y_1)$ and now you have $$2e^2 = \frac{y_2 - e^2}{x_2-1}$$ and so cross multiply to get $$y_2 -e^2 = 2e^2(x_2 -1) \implies \color{red}{y_2 = 2e^2x_2 -e^2}$$ and you are done !

The red equation above is the equation that you are looking for.

Comment: alternatively, you could use slope-intercept form: $y=mx+b$, and solve for $b$ by inputing $m=$slope and you point $(x,y)$

Comment: yes, that's also true